# Приложение запускается, но не видит jsp файлов

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

На xml это же приложение запускается, но когда попробовал его перевести на Java-config, то приложение, хоть и собралось, но не видит страницы index, выдает 404. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Исходный код](https://github.com/Vakarine/problem)

UPD:Artifact настроен так

[image: Artifact]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что вместо `getServletConfigClasses` класс конфига нужно было инжектить в `getRootConfigClasses`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]